# Excel IF containing ISBLANK for rows of dates

Tags: excel

I am trying to identify whether a row of dates contains a date that comes before or after another separate date. In addition, these rows might not contain any dates - they may be blank. So I just want to know if the entire row: contains date earlier than date1, contains date later than date1, or contains no dates (is blank). So I've been using the formula below, but it is not returning a blank field if the row is totally blank. Help with this?

=IF(MIN(AB2:AN2)< B2,"earlier",IF(MIN(AB2:AN2)>B2,"later", IF(ISBLANK(AB2:AN2),"")))

Comment: What does it return if the row is totally blank?

Comment: What happens if it has an earlier and a later?

Comment: Sorry the entire formula did not post properly (or I didn't copy it properly). Here it is: =IF(MIN(AB2:AN2)<B2,"earlier",IF(MIN(AB2:AN2)>B2,"later", IF(ISBLANK(AB2:AN2),"")))

Comment: Is earlier, then "earlier" returns, and same for later. Nothing happens if blank, though. It's as if it's just ignoring the ISBLANK statement.

Comment: @Evan Morgan: it is usually better to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51845890/edit) you question with additional information

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks - I am new and was looking for the "edit" button and simply didn't see it at first so I decided to comment. I'm getting the hang of it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISBLANK only returns `TRUE` for a single cell

I believe this:

```
=IF(COUNTA(AB2:AN2)=0,"",IF(MIN(AB2:AN2)<B2,"later","earlier"))
```

Will do what you need

Comment: Perfect, that worked! Thanks! I had tried the COUNTA(AB2:AN2)=0 but it was within another IF statement, and kept getting an error message. This simplified way is much better.